# What balance pitfalls result from simplifying the range of all D&D 5e spells to either Touch or Line-of-Sight?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, house-rules, everyday-heroes

For context, the *Everyday Heroes* product line is based on, and designed to be largely compatible with, D&D 5e. It is essentially a revival of the 3e *d20 Modern* line. Unlike the *d20 Modern Core Rulebook*, however, the *Everyday Heroes Core Rulebook* lacks any sort of magic mechanics. There is an "Everyday Arcana" product currently in development to pick up where the *d20 Modern* product *Urban Arcana* left off -- but until it launches, we're left with homebrew solutions for magic and spellcasting.

With that in mind, I am working on an adaptation of D&D 5e's magic rules to be bolted onto *Everyday Heroes* for use in a homebrew urban-fantasy setting. One of the changes I have in mind, partly for in-world lore reasons, would be to simplify all spell ranges to either **Touch** or **Line-of-Sight**. On top of the lore reasons, *Everyday Heroes* sees martially-oriented modern PCs routinely equipped with deadly longarms, grenade launchers, etc., many with ranges of 1000+ ft, and by default assumes they can fire all day long with only occasional reloads (see *EHCR* p. 298). So limiting spellcasters to ranges of 60 to 100 feet seems unnecessarily pedantic.

Still, I am mindful of creating more problems than I would be solving with this change. Am I  likely to run into balance issues here? Are there particular spells, or types of spells, that really need to be constrained to some mid-range between "whatever you can touch" and "whatever you can see"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**AoE spells originating from self**

You would need to consider how something like Thunderwave or Word of Radiance worked, because having them affect everything in line of sight is a pretty huge buff, and having them touch only is a pretty huge nerf.

**Range self buff spells balanced for caster class**

A spell like Mirror Image is balanced to protect a caster who is otherwise weak when attacked. There may be exploits around casting self-buffing spells on other classes where they could synergise very well with higher armour class, extra attack or other features. This synergy will happen at lower levels than equivalent multi-classing, so will be more impactful.

**Range self spells with concentration**

Some powerful effects are balanced by requiring concentration. When the spell has range of self and is useful in combat, the caster will now have the option of casting it on someone else and reduce or avoid the risk of losing the effect by taking cover. A good example of this kind of spell might be Vampiric Touch or Hex.

**Longer distance spells**

I would assume Teleport for example would keep the range?

**Spells of similar natures and different levels**

How would you separate Misty Step and Dimension Door if that both have the same range?

**Divination spells**

How would divination spells like Augury work that just give you answers? There is nothing to touch or see as a target.  Or spells like scrying, arcane eye, and clairvoyance, whose purpose is to provide information beyond line-of-sight?

**High Ground**

A high vantage point provides significant advantages. I picture a wizard in a plane, with a good pair of binoculars, sniping the king from tens of miles away. ... or possibly blowing up the enemy's satellites from the back of a pickup truck.

**What even is line-of-sight?**

"Line of sight" may open a Pandora's Box of ad-hoc adjudication that the medieval/renaissance-flavored standard D&D settings avoid by their normal tropes.

Does line-of-sight extend around corners if there's a mirror? Does it pass across a live video feed? Does it cross windows? Does it cross one-way mirrors (if so, does it cross in both directions)? Does it penetrate illusions or holograms?

... though, see [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/197764/20971) for a counter-argument to (some of?) this section.

**Who is "you" for secondary effects of self spells?**

Spells with range self use "you" to describe effects that impact the caster, and this will need adjudication. For example the spell Scrying has these modifiers:

> Knowledge Save Modifier:
> Secondhand (you have heard of the target) +5
> Firsthand (you have met the target) +0
> Familiar (you know the target well) −5

Seems like those "you" would refer to the touched creature, since it is directing the use of the spell?

However:

> On a successful save, the target isn’t affected, and you can’t use this spell against it again for 24 hours.

Seems like this "you" should be the caster? Otherwise the group could try multiple times to target the same individual, working around the limitation.

Comment: This is the kind of question where everyone might think of one new thing, so rather than have loads of right answers I opened this as a wiki so anyone can add to it. I hope that is ok and not too presumptuous.

Comment: Self-range AOE spells is a huge miss. Not sure how I managed that. Teleport spells are being addressed by excluding them from the game entirely. Should I edit the question to clarify that?

Comment: @screamline now it is in an answer I am not sure it needs adding to the question, but if you have any other exclusions they would be good to include.

Comment: For divination spells, I would think the distinction between touch and self would be relatively unimportant; it would just mean that a divination spell effect could be applied to another creature, which is exactly how, e.g., _guidance_ works. Is it a big deal balance-wise if spells like _augury_ could be applied to creatures other than the caster?

Comment: @screamline It's a big deal if you cannot ask about creatures that are not present.

Comment: @Kirt -- Maybe I'm missing your point. As I see it, _guidance_ functions when you apply it to another creature via touch. That creature can then gain the spell's benefit regardless of where it is and whether it's within the spell's original range at time of casting. Couldn't _augury_, or _commune_, or _detect thoughts_, etc., work the same way? Touch a creature -- which could be the caster herself -- and impart the benefit of the spell? Put differently, I guess, why is a spell with a range of self fundamentally different from a spell with a range of touch applied to the caster?

Comment: @screamline As far as the beneficiary of the spell, that's fine - no objection.  I was thinking more along the lines of the target of the divination.  For example, if the question for the augury is "Will it be weal or woe for us to enter the secret room on the second level?" would the result be "The secret room is not in line of sight - the spell doesn't work".  Similarly for any divination: scrying, clairvoyance, arcane eye, etc.

Comment: Just a note, in case the OP isn't aware on "Does it cross one-way mirrors (if so, does it cross in both directions)?" One-way mirrors aren't *actually* one-way. They're one-way only when it's dark on one side, and light on the other (and the one-way-ness is always that the dark side sees the light side, while the light side sees a mirror). Switch the lighting conditions, and they're one way in the other direction. They work by reflecting *most* light, so if you're on the light side, you're dazzled by the light reflected from your side, while the dark side has nothing to reflect.